# Different Boot configuration from STM32G431

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, keil

My set-up is a custom board with an STM32G431, using keil as the IDE and Jlink as the Debugger, and the HAL Libary from STM.
I need to boot my mcu with another configuration because I need the pin that's pulled on ground in the default configuration [Boot configurations, see reference manual s90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghnv2.png).My solution is to change the nSWBoot0 bit to 0 in the STM323G431xx.h. The Problem is to boot my setup on the MCU. If I download and verify, I can't get a good download. My solution is to use St Utillity with an StLink Debugger and change the bit there in the bit options. Do you guys know a solution without a STLink, preferred with a Segger product?

Comment: what I found with the first stm32g parts was that I had to actually run code to change these non volatile register bits.  could not do it with reads and writes through the debugger, so I wrote a simple program that was linked to run in ram, used the swd debugger to download that program and run it. Not sure if a power cycle was required after that, but was then able to change the register based boot bits (in my case i wanted the legacy boot0 pin internal bootloader experience, and once I figured this out that worked just fine).

Comment: should not matter which swd tool you use the arm core is the arm core, so ideally all the tools have the same access/features.

Comment: The access is the same, I actually prefer segger as is faster, more reliable and software is much better.(firmware and gdbserver)